# Why WSO2 DSS server is not getting started?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am trying to run my WSO2 DSS server, but whatever I do I am getting the same error:

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_09
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\WSO2DS~1.1\bin\..
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Here is the link to my `WSO2Server.bat`:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c9c107245c763637a4f182b7f2e3e867

Kindly let me know what I need to do inorder to run my WSO2 DSS successfully.
Ram of my system: 8GB. and using Windows 10.

Comment: Can you check the available memory?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne I didn't understood.. please can you tell me what you mean by memory availability

Comment: I mean when you start the machine check the available memory (after OS and other program take memory free available memory out of 8 GB)

Comment: There is much memory .. my friend. I have checked. but I don't understand still the wso2 is giving error

Comment: This is not a wso2 specific error. This error cause when starting the JVM. My gutt feeling is that you don't have enough free memory. Can you check changing the XmX and -XX:MaxHeapSize values. What is the DSS version?

Comment: My version is `WSO2 Data Services Server v3.5.1`

Comment: From your command line, it seems that you´re using a 32bits JVM. This will limit the ammount to ~ 1.5 GB. Your wso2server.bat is using -Xmx2048m, which is more than you´ll be able to allocate. Use a 64bits JVM or decrease the ammount of memory in wso2server.bat

Comment: I am using 64 bit. `java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)` check this

Comment: Well, your JAVA_HOME environment seems to disagree ;^) 
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_09

Comment: Is this the issue/.... well, I ran the WSO2 once.. this error I am facing the second time .. how is it possible?

Comment: Did you manually change the wso2server.bat ? Maybe this variable is being set there. Anyway, just make sure JAVA_HOME points to the correct path and you should be fine.

Comment: Hope so ... Let me check it

Comment: @PhilippeSevestre Thank you for your help.. it worked..

Comment: I´ve added the suggested change as an asnwer. Would you please care to accept it ?

Comment: @PhilippeSevestre Sure my friend....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to a 32-bit JVM, which does not support the default 2GB heap that is defined in wso2server.bat.

Please adjust your enviroment and/or define it explicitly in your wso2server.bat